# Load vector layer with QgsVectorLayer using MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, qgis, pymssql

I am trying to follow the instructions at the PyQGIS Cookbook to load a vector layer from an MSSQL connection but I am struggling!

http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html

I have successfully connected to a layer in PostGIS, but I want to connect to one using an MSSQL connection but cannot seem to make it work.

Firstly can we connect using MSSQL? Below is the key parts of my script, am I structuring the connection correctly?

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
# set host name, port, database name, username and password
uri.setConnection("myserver", "1433", "GGPNLPGRDC", "GGPAccessRDC", "GGPAccessRDC")
# set database schema, table name, geometry column and optionally
# subset (WHERE clause)
uri.setDataSource("dbo", "BLPU","GEOMETRY", "")

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "BLPU", "ogr")

if not vlayer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"
else:
    print "llpg_tan layer loaded successfully"
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Found what the problem was, I had to change 'ogr' to 'mssql' in the QgsVectorLayer parameters as follows...

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "BLPU", "mssql")

Comment: I am still having all kinds of issues with this.  Has this still been successful for you?

Comment: Yes this resolved the particular issue above, but I haven't progressed with any further development.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total novice QGIS user (1 week) however ...

In addition to the answer above, i found that i was not able to successfully create a valid layer until i explicitly set both the Srid and the WkbType.

In the case of the Srid, this is a bespoke Sql db with a geometry_columns table which seems to be utilised when using the UI, but not in the case of the python scripts.

In the case of the WkbType - i have both LineString and MultilineString in my table, i wasn't sure that mattered (again, it did not affect the layer diplay if i add the layer via the UI).

*My script is*:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("__the_host__", "1433", "__the_db_name__", "__username__", "__password__")
uri.setDataSource("dbo", "__table__", "SHAPE", "")
uri.setSrid('4326')
uri.setWkbType(5) # multilinestring
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "My Table", "mssql")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```